# Optimized/faster wikitext parsing in Mediawiki extension?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm currently working on a Mediawiki extension that needs to parse the wikitext on a page. Currently I use Parser::preprocess. This adds a few seconds to page load time.

Is there any faster way to do this? In particular, it has to parse wikitext, expand all templates and parser functions, and check for specific strings in the result.

Comment: Do it when the page is saved, store the result.

Comment: I need the parsed result in the userCan hook. Is there any variable where where I can cache the parsed result?

Answer (score 2):

Parsing is not an operation that you can reasonably expect to be fast; you should design your extension in such a way that it parsing only needs to happen when the wikitext of a page (or some of its dependencies) changes - ie. integrate any logic into one of the parser hooks, such as [`InternalParseBeforeSanitize`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/InternalParseBeforeSanitize) and store the results.

Normally you'd use the `page_props` table for that (cf. `ParserOutput::setProperty`) but if this is something security-related you should consider carefully if that works for you (it's per-page, not per-revision, and there is a small window beween the page and the props table getting updated). In some future MediaWiki version you'll be able to store arbitrary per-revision metadata in [MCR](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Multi-Content_Revisions) virtual slots; for now you have to implement it from scratch, in your own table, in the extension. Or you can always do some lightweight caching if you consider the delay acceptable on infrequently-viewed pages (use `ObjectCache::getMainWANInstance()` to get a [`WANObjectCache`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWANObjectCache.html) instance and use its `getWithSetCallback` method).

Comment: I just need a way to store the parsed wikitext between page loads. Preferably without database changes.

Comment: I expanded on non-DB caching a bit.

Comment: I read your updated answer (and thanks for the help). How persistent are these WAN caches? Just need a place to hold the parsed wikitext after each page save. As an added bonus, I wouldn't even need to reparse the wikitext - add a hook just before the page is displayed and grab the result.

Comment: Depends on your [`$wgMainCacheType`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMainCacheType) setting. They are intended for something like memcached or redis (ie. long-lived but not permanent as old data will be eventually evicted to make place for new) but entirely different configurations are possible (such as permanent DB-based key-value store, or no caching at all).

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, maybe it's possible to just use `ParserOutput::setExtensionData` to store the data on parsing, and then rely on the parser cache storing the parser output? I'm not familiar enough with the parser to say for sure if that would work.